# Problems with tabular-spacing for diagonal table header

Tags: tables, spacing

I want to put diagonal markers over words. I tried to implement this using a table and I'm almost satisfied with the result:

[image]

But as you can see, the spacings between the words of the sentence are too wide. I tried to solve it by putting the values of the first row into `\makebox` to give them an empty `width` apart of `2\tabcolsep`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

% \newcommand*{\diaghead}[1]{\rotatebox{45}{\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand*{\diaghead}[1]{\makebox[2\tabcolsep]{\rotatebox{45}{\texttt{#1}}}}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{l l l l l l l l l l l l l l}
    % \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c c c c c c c}
    % \begin{tabular}{r r r r r r r r r r r r r r}
        \diaghead{O} & \diaghead{O} & \diaghead{O} & \diaghead{B-Customer} & \diaghead{I-Customer} & \diaghead{I-Customer} & \diaghead{I-Customer} & \diaghead{I-Customer} & \diaghead{O} & \diaghead{O} & \diaghead{O} & \diaghead{O} & \diaghead{O} & \diaghead{...} \\
        Please & deliver & to & Example & Company & \& & Co. & Ltd. & Our & terms & and  & conditions & apply & ...
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Example for the BIO-Notation.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

which produces this:

[image]

It seems like there are still some spacings missing as the markers overlap.

Can someone help me out here by providing proper spacing? Or is there an alternative solution to get diagonal markers above words except of using `tikz`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it:

[image]

The key is to add the optional arrangement argument (found [here](http://www.weinelt.de/latex/makebox.html) (German language) to `\makebox` (in my case I used `l`). I also set the `\tabcolsep` to `4pt` for smaller spaces between the words. Here is the according MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\diaghead}[1]{\makebox[2\tabcolsep][l]{\rotatebox{45}{\texttt{#1}}}}
\begin{table}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \begin{tabular}{c c c c c c c c c c c c c c}
        \diaghead{O} & \diaghead{O} & \diaghead{O} & \diaghead{B-Customer} & \diaghead{I-Customer} & \diaghead{I-Customer} & \diaghead{I-Customer} & \diaghead{I-Customer} & \diaghead{O} & \diaghead{O} & \diaghead{O} & \diaghead{O} & \diaghead{O} & \diaghead{...} \\
        Please & deliver & to & Example & Company & \& & Co. & Ltd. & Our & terms & and  & conditions & apply & ...
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Example for the BIO-Notation.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I further improved it by using the package `tabularx` to fit into `\textwidth` (as the last diagonal marker might exceed it). I also added `\overbrace` and `\vphantom{gh}` (from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/520628/261955) answer) to align the braces at the same height. In addition, I shrinked the braces with `\scriptsize` because of some short words:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\diaghead}[1]{\makebox[2\tabcolsep][l]{\rotatebox{45}{\texttt{#1}}}}
\newcommand*{\textovbrace}[1]{$\tiny{\overbrace{\mbox{\normalsize{\vphantom{gh}#1}}}}$}
\begin{table}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c c c c c c c c c c c c c X}
        \diaghead{O} & \diaghead{O} & \diaghead{O} & \diaghead{B-Customer} & \diaghead{I-Customer} & \diaghead{I-Customer} & \diaghead{I-Customer} & \diaghead{I-Customer} & \diaghead{O} & \diaghead{O} & \diaghead{O} & \diaghead{O} & \diaghead{O} & \diaghead{...} \\
        \textovbrace{Please} & \textovbrace{deliver} & \textovbrace{to} & \textovbrace{Example} & \textovbrace{Company} & \textovbrace{\&} & \textovbrace{Co.} & \textovbrace{Ltd.} & \textovbrace{Our} & \textovbrace{terms} & \textovbrace{and } & \textovbrace{conditions} & \textovbrace{apply} & \textovbrace{...}
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Example for the BIO-Notation.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This is my final result:

[image]